# how to make quick launch bar in sharepoint capable of displaying filtered result?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-2003

I want the quick launch bar in share-point 2013 to display only those lists and pages that are allowed to a particular user.

That is it shouldn't display links that are not allowed to a particular user.

I am completely new to share-point environment.Is there any piece of code required for this purpose or this result can be obtained using some out of box features.

Answer (score 0):

You can use audiences to specificy per link in the quick navigation bar who should see the link. (Go to the site settings > navigation and edit the link to see the audiences option)

Meaning: you hide the link but that content will still be available if the user travels to the URI by other ways.